# Grunt-sass can't compile sass maps?

Tags: sass, gruntjs

I want to use **[this MQ Mixin](https://github.com/guardian/sass-mq)**, but I'm getting an error when trying to compile this mixin:

> Warning: C:/xxxxx/mq:13: error: error reading values after mobile

I'm using Grunt with [grunt-sass](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-sass) plugin to compile my sass. My first thought was that I am using the old version of grunt-sass that does not support sass maps, and I was partially right because I was using the older version. Quick update to the latest version (at the moment - 0.14.0) and nothing, still getting same error. Also I checked if the error occurs with ruby-sass (v.3.3.14) but does't, file compiles properly. So, what's going on with grunt-sass? What am I missing here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you readme for grunt-sass, it says it is using libsass, which is not even close to the same thing as the official version written in Ruby.  It frequently lags behind in features and is known to compile incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As cimmanon mentioned, grunt-sass is using libsass, which is far behind on features. You should use [grunt-contrib-sass](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass) instead, which compiles using Ruby sass. You will need Ruby and the sass gem installed for it to work.